# how to use boost context v2

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

boost::context library was updated to version v2 and the changes broke all my previous code relying on boost::jump_fcontext()

Also the old boost::jump_fcontext() is no longer available in the new API. The new boost::context v2 changed so much that I can't understand it. The boost provided examples don't help me.

Here is pseudo code of the program structure I'm trying to archive with the new execute_context:

```
struct myctx
{
    int var;
    boost::context::execution_context fctx;
    myctx()
        : var(0), fctx("how to ctor")
    {}
    static void ctx_func(ctx_data * ptr) {

        while(ptr->var++ < 1000) {
            ptr->fctx("how to jump into main() myctx ??")
        }
    }
};
int main()
{    
    myctx mctx;
    while(1)
        mctx.fctx("how to jump into ctx_func() ??");
    return 0;
}
```

How do I replace those strings with real C++?? I don't understand what are the possible arguments to `boost::context::execution_context`

My usage of the boost::context was that I saved the current context into myctx and switched into multiple other myctx's in unordered fasion. With boost::jump_fcontext this was fairly clearly done.

Comment: What is "pure C++11"? As opposed to what? Is `int main()` pure?

Comment: I meant by "pure C++11" that it uses all new C++11 features in the API, like auto, tuples and lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont't you initialize 'fctx'? Even it will not compile because of ctx_data() - ctor (not same name as myctx) ...
maybe you meant something like:

```
struct myctx
{
    int var;
    execution_context< myctx * > fctx;

    myctx()
        : var(0), fctx( myctx::ctx_func)
    {}

    static execution_context< myctx * > ctx_func(execution_context< myctx * > mctx, ctx_data * ptr) {
        while(ptr->var++ < 1000) {
            // jump into main()
            std::tie(mctx, ptr) = mctx( ptr);
        }
        return std::move( mctx);
    }
};
```

I've no idea for what you want to pass myctx pointer

Comment: Thank you. The pointer's purpose in my code is actually irrelevant as it just passes some additional data in/out of ctx_func(). I just wanted to know how to do it with v2.